# How to make a C++ macro which checks condition, prints error if not met and executes user block?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to make an assertion-like macro that can be used like so

```
CHECKED_LOG(window != nullptr, "Window must be initialized")
{
    DoSomethingCleanupFunction();
    return false;
}
```

which should expand to something like

```
if (!(EXPR))
{
    LOG_MESSAGE("Error: window != nullptr : " + MSG);
    { /* user block */ }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without overcomplicating source code with some kind of classes, that use RAII to call all that logic and without double call of `!(EXPR)`? I also want that to look natural, not

```
CHECKEDLOG(...)
  Logic();
} // <---- closing brace with opening one
```

Maybe some preprocessor placeholders for block after the macro of braces magic?

In the end i want something like that:

```
bool Initialize()
{
   window = InitWindow();
   CHECKED_LOG(window != nullptr, "Couldn't initialize window")
   {
       Stop();
       return false;
   }

   inputHandler = InitInputHandler();
   CHECKED_LOG(inputHandler != nullptr, "Couldn't initialize input handler")
   {
       Stop();
       return false;
   }
}
```

and the expansion

```
bool Initialize()
{
   window = InitWindow();
   if (! (window != nullptr))
   {
       LOG_ERROR("window != nullptr", "Couldn't initialize window");
       Stop();
       return false;
   }

   inputHandler = InitInputHandler();
   if (! (inputHandler != nullptr))
   {
       LOG_ERROR("inputHandler != nullptr", "Couldn't initialize input handler");
       Stop();
       return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: It is ambiguous what you want. Can you show some code that actually does what you want to have happen?

Comment: @jxh if i could then i hadn't created the question

Comment: Ok, it is more clear now.

Comment: Do you require the syntax to be that way? Why not use lambda expressions? Why not use exception handling?

Comment: @jxh i've added some examples of what i want in the end. Lambda still requires me to place braces. Could you post an example? I don't like exceptions because of the bloating of the source code with try-catch and a lot of possible nested try-catches

Comment: @Herrgott - If your code is filled with lots of try/catch blocks, you're not writing idiomatic C++ (most of which should be exception neutral and not care one way or the other if exceptions get thrown).  RAII usually makes it pretty simple to achieve this.

Comment: @stephennewell so my code is not filled with lots of try-catches. I'm writing a class that calls functions from C-library which return `int`s or pointers as the result and i want to check them in a good way. If one of them fails then report it and make initialization failed (return false). And i want to avoid a lot of boilerplate

Comment: Are you looking for `##EXPR`? And why does this have to be a macro?

Comment: @user207421 i'm looking for a way to embed block defined after the macro in the if statement right after some logging function which internally does `##EXPR` for logging. That is not valid because if cannot have 2 expressions without braces and i don't want to make extra braces after my block

Comment: One way: embed the block as a macro argument. https://tio.run/##XZBPa4NAEMXv@ymeelGwknO0hWLElv5JSVvoIRDUHePCZjdslFCCn91uTFqkc5lh5vHej6n2@5ttVQ2eUJXsOCER@tAaKnZ3jHmcaqEIz8s8z1ZYM1xL1PAdqbcbUkUpiQc49SB5IBxaPp9XZAxjpdYSExFu0ZqO4uHXNn3I0qdssbH2fvb1tgrx8p6HuE8/HpevwSSO60viqAps2OR2ritfksBd6MaBC@@stL0uhE2e28kerfu5jYikuIz/2VyCp9sex8Ya@LOAMaFa7Aqh4FuAUTHln4VwPxvoJooiN/wzOF0fort2xMu15uU3hajsJySO2kjurJUbT0AMtZ1RmMXog5j1w/AD

Comment: @jxh There's an issue i didn't mention earlier. My `LOG` macro uses `__VA_ARGS__` and i have to move block argument to the first or second place which makes it look weird and complicated to read

Comment: Another way: use a function to check and log and return the result of the check. https://tio.run/##XVBBTsMwELz7FVv3kkih6jkpXNooSIBARUgcKlWJvU0sXLtyHAFCeXuwnba0@LLy7szszLLD4aZmbJgKxWTHERZCt9Zgub8jZMpxJxTC43NR5GvYEDg@sYNoInW9RVVWEnkMPz2gbBFay9OUoTGEVFpLuADBLVjTYTaEAWuQfWx3pXCTKHTw62CSUcA5EKoGrpvrxr6t3SpytuAp8cneYuEJvjiYL4GJisssMAzazigIpIz0f/GW9/nyIV9tnU6Uv7@sE3h6LeJ/ca/8BlicAF3pZgIUpv7v6jhOgY4SMSFCWdiXQkF0Mn65be4k3hrQzWw2oyeAf@MZdWd9DlpozatvTIC5@0n41EbyyUbR7Iw/ZpuPnZ70w/AL

Comment: @jxh there is no way to log `__file__` and `__line__` in the second approach because `LOG` is `do while(0)` thing and all the needed formatting occur in the logging library

Comment: why not use an inline function instead [link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/inline-functions#inline-vs-macros)

Comment: Just pass `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to the function.

Comment: Did you consider *generating* C++ code with tools like [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) - or your own one (using [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/)...)

Comment: @Basilestarynkevitch no, this would be an overengineering for my crazy idea

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this without overcomplicating source code with some kind of classes, that use RAII to call all that logic and without double call of !(EXPR)?

Put `LOG_MESSAGE` inside `if` with a comma operator that evaluates to true.

```
#define CHECKED_LOG(EXPR, MSG) \
    if (!(EXPR) && (LOG_MESSAGE("Error: " #EXPR " : " + MSG), 1))
```

I would name this macro just `IF_NOT_THEN_LOG` or similar, first so that developer knows it's an `if`, then - `CHECKED` is an adjective, there is no object here, `EXPR` is something to do so you `if` on that expression.

Overall, there is a fear associated with such macros. They hide a flow control statement, they usually lead to more complicated code and end up in a spaghetti code. Lambda, RAII and exception handling were invented into the language because it's simpler, clearer and more safe to work with them.